# Reading Serial Data

Tags: c#, wpf, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to build a WPF application that will take in serial data from an Arduino. The Arduino will send a '1' when the user turns an encoder and the WPF will take this one and turn up the volume 1 tick.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string comPort = "COM6";
        SerialPort mySerialPort = SerialPortCommunications(comPort);
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataRecieved);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        mySerialPort.DiscardInBuffer();

    }
private void OnDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialDevice = sender as SerialPort;
        string indata;
        indata = serialDevice.ReadExisting();
        MessageBox.Show(indata);
        MessageBox.Show("Fired");

    }
public SerialPort SerialPortCommunications(string comPort)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(comPort);
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        //mySerialPort.DiscardNull = true;
        return mySerialPort;
    }
```

The issue I am having is unless the arduino is constantly sending data my event will not fire. This is fixed by constantly sending a 0 from the arduino, however when I need to receive my 1 to signal the volume change I cannot sort out the input buffer. I built a console application with the same code as above that waits for user input in the main that does have the issue. The arduino can be silent for an hour and when the hour is up the data sent will display on the console. Ideally in my WPF the channel will be silent until data to signal changes are received.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to wait for data to be recevied and parse it to an int, then if the result equal 1 you can fire your desired function

```
private void OnDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialDevice = sender as SerialPort;
        var indata = serialDevice.ReadExisting();
        int DigitFromArduino = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(indata,out DigitFromArduino))
            if(DigitFromArduino == 1)
            {
                // call your function to increase the volum
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have played around with this decoding data in this manner however the main issue of the event itself not firing remains. Meaning I never break into this logic.